# Why does my tab functions doesn't work on the other items?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a Pokedex App. I wanted to create multiple tabs where I can see the information about the pokemon, but I cant seem to switch to the other tabs on other items. It worked perfectly fine on the 1st item(bulbasaur), but doesn't work on the others. I can't seem to find the solutions to it. Really appreciate the help.

Here is the HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="pokemon-name"></ul>
    <div id="pokemon-modal"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[data-tab-content]{
    display: none;
}

.active[data-tab-content]{
    display: block;
}

.tab{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab.active{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.tab:hover{
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

JS:

```
const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemon-name")
const pokemonModal = document.getElementById("pokemon-modal")


const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    const promises = []
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`
        promises.push(fetch(url).then((res) => res.json()))
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
        const pokemonData = result.map((data) => ({
            name: data.name,
            id: data.id,
            image: data.sprites['front_default'],
            types: data.types[0].type.name,
            weight: data.weight,
            stats: data.stats[0].base_stat,
            abilities: data.abilities[0].ability.name,
        }))
        
        displayPokemon(pokemonData)
        modalDisplayPokemon(pokemonData)
    })
}

const displayPokemon = (pokemonData) => {

    const pokemonHTML = pokemonData.map(pokemon => `
    <li class="card">
        <img src='https://pokeres.bastionbot.org/images/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png'/>
        <h3>${pokemon.name}</h3>
        <p>${pokemon.types}</p>
        <button class="openModalBtn" data-modal='modal${pokemon.id}'>See more</button>
    </li>
    `).join('')

    pokemonName.innerHTML = pokemonHTML
}

const modalDisplayPokemon = (pokemonData) => {
    const modalPokemonHTML = pokemonData.map(pokemon => `
    <div id="modal${pokemon.id}" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-card">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="closeModalBtn">&times</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <img src='https://pokeres.bastionbot.org/images/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png'/>
                <h3>${pokemon.name}</h3>
                <p>${pokemon.types}</p>
                <ul>
                    <li data-tab-target="#about" class="tab active">About</li>
                    <li data-tab-target="#stats" class="tab">Stats</li>
                    <li data-tab-target="#abilities" class="tab">Abilities</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="about" class="active" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Weight: ${pokemon.weight}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="stats" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Base Stats: ${pokemon.stats}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="abilities" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Abilities: ${pokemon.abilities}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `).join(' ')
    pokemonModal.innerHTML = modalPokemonHTML

    modalBtn()
    tabContent()
}

const modalBtn = () => {
    const openModalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.openModalBtn')
    const closeModalBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.closeModalBtn')

    openModalBtn.forEach(openBtn => {
        openBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const modal = openBtn.getAttribute('data-modal')

            document.getElementById(modal).style.display = 'block'
        })
    })

    closeModalBtn.forEach(closeBtn => [
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const modal = closeBtn.closest('.modal')
            modal.style.display = "none"
        })
    ])

    window.onclick = (e) => {
        if(e.target.className === 'modal'){
            e.target.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}

const tabContent = () => {
    const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-target]')
    const tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-content]')

    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const target = document.querySelector(tab.dataset.tabTarget)
            tabContents.forEach(tabContent => {
                tabContent.classList.remove('active')
            })
            tabs.forEach(tab => {
                tab.classList.remove('active')
            })
            tab.classList.add('active')
            target.classList.add('active')
        })
    })
}

fetchPokemon()
```

To check the full code, you can check it here:
https://codepen.io/ifarhandika/pen/gOmWNoV

Comment: What do you mean with _doesn't work on the others_ ?

Comment: your code not adding active class to "data-tab-content" when respective tab is clicked.

Comment: @Sfili_81 you can check on my codepen link I attached. Try switching tabs on the other items such as ivysaur or venusaur. The switching tabs function doesnt work on them.

Comment: @nagarajgoud I noticed that but I cant seem to know where to put that line of codes